# C++ Qt Timer For Each Object

Tags: c++, qt, class, timer

How can implement Timer for each object

for example i have class like this

---------------------------------------> person.h

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class person;
}

class person : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit person(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~person();
    QString Name;
    QTimer *timer;

private:
    Ui::person *ui;
signals:

public slots:

    void onTimer();
private slots:

};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

person.cpp ---------------------->

```
#include "person.h"
#include "ui_person.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

person::person(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::person)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    timer=new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this,SLOT(this->onTimer()));
    timer->start(1000);

}

person::~person()
{
    delete ui;
}



void person::onTimer()
{
    qDebug() << "timer call for "<< Name  ;
```

------------------> main.cpp

```
#include "person.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    person first;
    person second;
    first.Name="jack";
    second.Name="frank";




    return a.exec();
}
```

this code work but the timer should interval in constructor and both of object have same interval!

[OUtPut picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTlaH.jpg)

you can see the out put in attached image

Problem is I want start , setInterval the Timer with object like:

```
person first;
first Name= "jack";
first.timer->start(200);
person second;
second Name "frank";
second.timer->start(500);
```

and after my command timer start work not in constractor

in my code when i try to inpet `first.timer` the ponter sign `->` didnt apear!!! and not working

Comment: you can also post your question here https://forum.qt.io/

Answer (score 2):

When you construct your `person` object, you get a new copy of each data member variable for each instance of the object.

Therefore, you will have a new `QObject* timer` for `person john` and for `person frank`.

However, timer is only a pointer, so you need to construct the timer in the constructor of your `person` class.

```
timer = new QTimer();
```

A timer is kind of useless if you don't specify a mechanism to receive notification when the timer has expired.

As such you need to specify a callback.

Prior to C++11 and Qt5, the callback for the timer expiry has to be a class which inherits from `QObject`.

However, with the advent of C++11 and Qt5, you can use lambdas for callback functions, so you can specify your callback as follows:

```
person::person()
{
    timer = new QTimer();
    QObject::connect(timer, QTimer::timeout, [this]()
        {
            this->onTimer();
        });
}
```

Now when you call, eg, `john.timer->start(2000)`, the callback `person::onTimer` will be called after 2 seconds.

So you need to create a callback function, for example:

```
void person::onTimer()
{
    std::cout << timer called for " << Name.toStdString() << '\n';
}
```

Whether you use a `QObject` derived design, or lambdas, depends on the needs of your design.

I would recommend reading [Qt for Beginners](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners) on the qt wiki.

Answer (score 0):

first of all what is your timer going to do, cause if it needs to call onTimeout the person class method, you need to inherit from QObject and specify the Q_OBJECT macro under your class name, then create the slot handling the signal from the timer and in the constructor instantiate the your qtimer pointer and connect its signal to this instance slot